# Non-flattened icon in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, icons, app-store, appstore-approval

I submitted my app to the iTunes App Store for approval a little while ago.

Today I realized that the application icon was not flattened, as required (suggested?) in the Apple guidelines. As I understand it, a flattened icon has no transparencies, but mine does.

My dilemma is this. If I flatten the icon and resubmit the app, I lose all this time that the app has already been sitting in the approval process. If I do nothing and Apple denies my app, I will have lost even more time.

So my question is this: is a flattened icon a requirement or a suggestion? Will Apple deny my app based on the fact, that my icon has transparencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know one App with a half transparent App Icon, the Dutch application to watch TV, called Uitzendinggemist (Probably only available in the Dutch App Store)

I think you must hope that it will be alright. If it will be denied anyway, re-uploading the binary with the correct Icon will probably take less time to approve, I suppose.